# How to teleport an iron golem with a specific name to a specific location?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How would you teleport an iron golem called 1 to the coordinates -76 101 -4 in Minecraft bedrock?

Comment: What have you tried? We appreciate the effort here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command:

`tp @e[type=iron_golem,name="1"] -76 101 -4`

It teleports an entity `@e` with the specifications with type iron golem `type=iron_golem` and the name `name="1"` to the location `-76 101 -4`

> If it worked, please mark the answer as solved to help others with the same problem